# Cypress: How to read a text file, but keep execution going even if file does not exist?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I want to write to a text file, but if it exists already, I'd like to clean it first.

If it does not exist, I want create it and start writing to it.

I made several attempts to clear the file in case it exists but also continue execution if it doesn't, but the method

```
cy.readFile()
```

always crashed my execution in case it didn't find the file.

For example:

```
function clearFile(filePath) {
  try {
    // Read the contents of the file.
    const fileContents = cy.readFile(filePath, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  
    // If the file exists, clear it.
    if (fileContents) {
      cy.writeFile(filePath, "");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore the error if the file does not exist.
    if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
      // The file does not exist.
    } else {
      // Rethrow the error if it is not a file not found error.
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

In the case file does not exist - catch is not being reached as I meant it would be.

Please advice.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to clean the file - `cy.writeFile()` will overwrite it!

If you just call `cy.writeFile(newData)`, none of the old data will remain in the file. It will simply overwrite the previous content.

That's why there's an [option to append](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#Append-contents-to-the-end-of-a-file)

> **Append contents to the end of a file**
>
> ```js
> cy.writeFile('path/to/message.txt', 'Hello World', { flag: 'a+' })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile

> By default, cy.readFile() asserts that the file exists and will fail
> if it does not exist. It will retry reading the file if it does not
> initially exist until the file exists or the command times out.

If you attempt creating and writing to a file that already exists, the old file will be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you Eriks for the insight. Do you have another way for me to acheive my goal?

Comment: Simply do a cy.writeFile(filePath, "whatever"); and it will create or overwrite your file. There is no need to clean anything. A caveat is that permissions/lack of disk space/non-existing path/etc may prevent the system from creating the file. You still may want to wrap file operations with try-catch and async behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `cy.readFile()` and `cy.writeFile()` should work for cypress. If it's not, I think you're using `cy.readFile()` for the purpose that is outside of your `cypress` framework. If that is the case then you should consider using ***[`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)*** module provided by node. If I have to write your requirement using `fs` module, it goes something like:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function clearFile(filePath) {
  try {
    // Check if the file exists.
    fs.accessSync(filePath);
    
    // If the file exists, clear it.
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, '');
  } catch (err) {
    // If the file does not exist, create it.
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, '');
    } else {
      // Rethrow the error if it is not a file not found error.
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Read-a-file-that-might-not-exist) for that specific situation. Basically, they recommend the same approach as `@Eriks Klotins` does, but suggest to wrap it inside `cy.task`:

> **Read a file that might not exist**
>
> Command cy.readFile() assumes the file exists. If you need to read a
> file that might not exist, use cy.task.

```
// in test
cy.task('readFileMaybe', 'my-file.txt').then((textOrNull) => { ... })


// cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        readFileMaybe(filename) {
          if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
            return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
          }

          return null
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```